# can i reference a script contained in a different namespace?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 3 folders in my project, named scripts, photon and standard assets. Now I need to make a reference from the standard assets folder to a script in the 'scripts' folder, which is possible only if I copy the folder into the standard assets(because it has a different namespace).But I get an error with the photon.So is there a way to make a reference without copying the folder?

```
 using UnityEngine;
 namespace UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput
{
public class ButtonHandler : MonoBehaviour
{  
  public  wepScript  ws; //error cannot find  wepScript 
}
}


  using UnityEngine;
  using System.Collections;

 public class wepScript : MonoBehaviour {
                   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `namespace` is not something related to the Unity. You can use whatever `namespace` or `code` in your classeses. You just need to include the namespace via using.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
```

For example:
I have a script under `Standard Assets` folder called `Weapon`.

```
using UnityEngine;
namespace FooNamespace
{
    public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour {

        public void LogMeUp()
        {
            Debug.Log("I have been called");
        }
    }
}
```

And then, I have `GonnaCallWeapon` script somewhere else.

```
using UnityEngine;

using FooNamespace;

public class GonnaCallWeapon : MonoBehaviour {
    public Weapon weapon;
    void Start () {
        weapon.LogMeUp();
        Debug.Log("I called LogMeUp");
    }
}
```

- I have attached my `Weapon`, and `GonnaCallWeapon` scripts to an object in the hierarchy, and set up the `weapon` variable.

[image: Example]

Comment: i want to refer a script say "weapon" from the standard assets cross platform namespace, how do i do it? now i get an error because it cannot detect the weapon script.

Comment: thank you, my issue being that weapon has no namespace. gonnacallweapon is inside a namespace

Comment: Like I said, doesn't matter which one has a namespace. Just add the namespace via `using`statement.

`using FooNamespace;`

Comment: Then, I think your issue is a reference issue. In monodevelop, right click **References** folder under **Assembly-CSharp**, and select **Edit References**. And under **Projects** tab, select **Assembly-CSharp-firstpass**. That's it. But I think this is not a good solution.